# Refer to one single SQL query 3 times on a page, and create 3 separate loops off that query?

Tags: php, sql, forms

What I'm trying to accomplish is a back-end Admin panel, with multiple forms to edit tables from a database.

I would like to run one SQL query on the page, & refer to it multiple times (**possibly creating 3 different loops out of this same query, without having to query it more than once**).

*I can't figure out how to make the query work outside of its initial loop*, if possible at all.

I already have the SQL statement that would work on all the forms (since basically my forms just query the same 2 tables over & over again), but I can't use it more than once...
I already tried it, but can't get it to work.

**I just want to run this query once, & simply refer back to it whenever I need to use it again on the page.** (Perhaps by creating a new *while* loop? Tried it, doesn't work. Use different variables? Doesn't work. I'm itching to find out what DOES...)

This Admin panel is a single PHP page, divided by compartments based on administrative tasks.

For some idea, it is like so ~

---

### // UPLOAD PHOTO //

*(options available are...)*
- Upload photo
- Add Photo Title
**01.** Select Category **|| SQL QUERY!** LOOP **-** Drop-down list of Categories
**02.** Select Sub-categories **|| SQL QUERY!** LOOP **-** Checkbox list of Categories + Sub-categories
- Add Tags
- Add Photo Description / Commentary

### // MANAGE CATEGORIES //

*(options available are...)*
- Create a new Category
**03.** Delete Multiple Categories **|| SQL QUERY!** LOOP **-** Checkbox list of Categories + # of entries each
**04.** Rename Category **|| SQL QUERY!** LOOP **-** List of Categories
**05.** Edit Sub-Category **|| SQL QUERY!** LOOP **-** List of Sub-categories

---

So on & so forth...
As you can see, all queries made are related to Categories.

I actually have completed a working version of this but one with too many SQL queries on just a single page (for the exact same tables over & over again), it just seems impractical and thoughtless. There has got to be a better way...

The query I'd like to use just once (& the one I'm using right now) is:

```sql
$sql = "SELECT category.id, category.name, COUNT(records.category_id) as number
FROM category
    LEFT OUTER
        JOIN records
        ON category.id = records.category_id
WHERE
    category.active = 1
GROUP
    BY category.id
ORDER
    BY category.name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "SAMPLE LOOP" . $rows['id'] . $rows['name'] . $rows['number']; }
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?
**Thank you for your time and wisdom!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the results to a new array and you can then iterate over that when you need to:

```
$sql = "SELECT category.id, category.name, COUNT(records.category_id) as number
FROM category
    LEFT OUTER
        JOIN records
        ON category.id = records.category_id
WHERE
    category.active = 1
GROUP
    BY category.id
ORDER
    BY category.name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$saved_results = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "SAMPLE LOOP" . $rows['id'] . $rows['name'] . $rows['number']; 
    array_push($saved_results, $rows);
}
```

Then whenever you want:

```
foreach($saved_results as $res) {
  dostuff();
}
```

Comment: Omg, it pays to ask! That was incredibly quick @Ilion! Took me a while to respond since I had to test & integrate, but THANK YOU so much for that! I didn't think there was a way, but I'm now a believer! LOL